# Add Icon to Mapbox-GL (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, mapbox

I'm pretending to include a icon into my map from mapboxgl in my angular proyect. Im following the JS API ([API for Javascript](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/)) but I'm doing in Typescript. I tried to adapt it and this is my code:

```
iconoDron(){
this.mapa.on('load', function() {
  this.mapa.loadImage(
   'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Cat_silhouette.svg/400px-Cat_silhouette.svg.png',
  function(error, image){
    if (error) throw error;
    this.mapa.addImage('cat', image);
    this.mapa.addSource('point', {'type': 'geojson','data': {'type': 'FeatureCollection','features': [{ 'type': 'Feature','geometry': {'type': 'Point','coordinates': [0, 0]}}]}});
    this.mapa.addLayer({'id': 'points','type': 'symbol','source': 'point','layout': {'icon-image': 'cat','icon-size': 0.25}});
  }
  );
```

But it does not work!. Something wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "it does not work"? Is the image not rendering? Are you getting any errors in the console? It would be helpful if you could share a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) reproducing the issue. The code you shared looks quite similar to the functioning example so the issue might be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Used a similar syntax for setting a .png image as a custom marker. The only difference was the callbacks of the 'on' and 'loadImage' were arrow functions.